# Igraph random number generator in c

Tags: c, multithreading, igraph

I was wondering wether the igraph_rng_default() gives a thread safe random number generator or not, and if that's the case, what rng should I use? Furthermore, if you call igraph_sbm_game in every thread, the generation of these graphs is thread safe?

---

Edit:
to be more clear, this is what I wrote in my program:

```
  #define N 2048
  #define R 16
  #define rngseed 1763984
 int main(void)
 {   
  igraph_rng_seed(igraph_rng_default(), rngseed);  
 #pragma omp parallel shared(some_shared_variables) private(some_private_variables)
 { 
   igraph_matrix_t pref_matrix;    
   igraph_matrix_init(&pref_matrix, R, R);
   igraph_vector_int_t block_sizes;
    /*SBM initialization*/ 
    igraph_vector_int_init(&block_sizes, R);
   ...
   ...
   #pragma omp for ordered schedule(static,1)//ordered schedule(static,1) per risultati in ordine #pragma omp ordered per stampare in ordine    
    for(q1=0;q1<100;q1++)
    { 
      igraph graph; 
      igraph_sbm_game(&graph, N, &pref_matrix, &block_sizes, IGRAPH_DIRECTED, IGRAPH_NO_LOOPS);
      ....
    }
  }
```

My question is, since igraph_sbm_game generates a random graph based on the  chosen rng, is this randomness guaranteed to be thread safe? In other words, with the default igraph random number generator, do I get random numbers in a thread safe way? My doubt comes both from the fact that the igraph_sbm_game() function doesn't need a seed and the fact that I can't find which random number generator is used by igraph...

Comment: I think you should elaborate the question. What do you mean with thread safe random number generator? Did you tried it and found some issue? See also [ask].

Comment: Even if it is thread-safe, it is probably better to use a separate RNG for each thread, because then there is no chance of contention of the default RNG.

Comment: How do I call separate rngs in different threads?

Answer (score 2):

igraph is not designed to be thread-safe - there are certain data structures (such as a global "cleanup" stack for pointers that igraph allocates during the course of a function) that are shared between threads, so it is not safe to call two igraph functions at the same time from different threads. This probably answers your original question: no, the random number generator is not thread-safe either.

There is an experimental switch in its `./configure` script (`--enable-tls`) that moves the global data structures into thread-local storage if the compiler supports it. This has the potential of making igraph thread-safe as long as you don't manipulate the *same* graph from different threads (or you use locking to coordinate access to the graph). However, this has not been tested thoroughly, so proceed carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Some updates valid for igraph version 0.9.x:

As the other answer says, igraph has limited thread support when compiled with thread-local storage enabled. To do so, [set `IGRAPH_ENABLE_TLS` to `ON`](https://igraph.org/c/html/latest/igraph-Installation.html#igraph-Installation-notable-configuration-options) when building igraph.

Issues relating to thread support are documented here:

- https://igraph.org/c/html/latest/igraph-Advanced.html#using-igraph-in-multi-threaded-programs

In a nutshell:

- If thread support was enabled, then the macro `IGRAPH_THREAD_SAFE` is defined to `1`.
- The default random number generator that is active on startup is not thread-safe.
- You will need to explicitly initialize, seed and set a separate random number generator for each thread, using `igraph_rng_set_default()`. Only then will it be safe to use igraph functions that use random numbers from multiple threads.